# What is the "Mayday Mayday Mayday" procedure in French?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, radio

"Mayday" is an emergency procedure word used as a distress signal in voice procedure radio communications in English.

What would be the equivalent in French?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mayday is phonetically transcribing the ungrammatical French "*M'aidez !*".

This expression is never used as is in spoken French. Idiomatic ones are "*Aidez moi !*", "*A l'aide !*" or "*Au secours !*".

Mayday is rarely heard either in French radio communication outside a potentially international context (planes/boats). For ground communications, one might prefer instead "***Urgent ! Urgent ! Urgent !***" to interrupt any ongoing communication.

Mayday was coined by [Frederick Stanley Mockford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Stanley_Mockford) from the correct French "*Venez m'aider !*".

Comment: Mieux que le mien, donc accepté, +1 et l'original effacé!  **;-)**

Comment: "Mayday mayday mayday" _is_ used in France. See [Memo from the Glénans](http://memovoile.free.fr/Technique/Moniteurs/Securite-Vie%20a%20bord/ext/Glenans%20-%20Urgence%20-%20MAYDAY%20VHF%20en%20phonie.pdf) (a well-known sailing teaching company).

Comment: @anderstood Granted. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

This is an international distress signal; it is also "Mayday mayday mayday" in France, see [mayday on the French wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayday).

Answer (score 2):

MAYDAY is arguably more French than English, but MAYDAY is certainly the standard expression for this condition in the English-speaking world, which, by international agreement, includes aviation.

This agreement does not preclude local languages from being used, but during critical phases of flight, standardized terms are highly recommended.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_communication:

Introduction

> ...as deemed by the International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO),
>   English is the official language of aviation.

Aviation English

> Many non-native English speaking pilots and air traffic controllers
>   learn English during their flight training and use it in a highly
>   practical level while safely operating an aircraft...